# how to echo path to mysql on a shared server?

Tags: php, mysql

I am on a shared server running Apache hosted at zenutech.com.

I am trying to set up a wordpress plugin called [sitepush](http://rowatt.com/sitepush) and to do so I need the full path to both mysql and mysqldump, my problem is i don't have ssh to the box  and it's somewhere above where i currently have access via ftp.

Can i echo it via php or phpmyadmin maybe?

Is there any other way i can find it out?

So far I've tried:

`/var/lib/mysql`
and
`/usr/bin/mysql`
neither work.

Comment: Try: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have ssh access, then you just need to issue the following (bash) commands:

```
which mysql
which mysqldump
```

---

If you have no shell access, you can issue the following SQL query:

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name = "basedir"
```

It will likely return

```
/usr
```

which means, that the executables are at `/usr/bin`. However if it returns something different from `/usr` that just add `/bin/mysql` to that and you'll get the full path.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Backtics are not posix and therefore deprecated in bash. which version you are using?

Comment: Nevermind, I only skimmed the text above and assumed you were posting PHP code since "echo $()" is not needed in bash, you can directly use `which`.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Yeah, you are right of course.. I'm currently have my after-lunch sleepiness, sorry :)

Comment: you two are debating my question how funny!

Answer (score 2):

You could try using `which` from PHP, if you don't have shell access:

```
<?php
echo `which mysql` . PHP_EOL;
echo `which mysqldump` . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: ok Iv'e tried this but I'm a real dunce when it comes to php it just echos a blank page...